How to block internet access to computer but allow LAN access?
I have a couple old Windows XP and Windows 7 machines that I would like to use, but am obviously worried about security.
I've heard that Windows XP will be attacked while idle; even if it doesn't actually browse the Internet.
So, I'd like these computers to be available on my LAN for file share and local-only RDP, but in no way connected to the internet.
I have a fairly nice LinkSys EA8300 router. I see no where to lock it down and still have LAN work.
So, is this possible?

You certainly can allow VLANs to communicate with each other but block outgoing traffic on a specific VLAN but even then I would argue these operating systems are NOT safe to use

Why not update the devices to a safe OS, such as a currently-supported version of Linux? Even if one or both are ancient 32-bit machines, there are numerous Linux distros that have updated security. https://www.debugpoint.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/, https://itsfoss.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/  [A 32-bit Acer D250 I use when traveling is also far faster under Linux than  it was under Windows, as well.]

I'm aware of and have used many Linux distros for over 20 years.  I currently have 2 Linux machines running.  But keep in mind that our hands are often tied in technology, and we will have to do the thing we shouldn't do.

If you need to ask the question, it may not be a great idea to do it (and your question appears contradictory with reference to RDP)  but you can limit access to your LAN only -
One way to do this is to set up the devices with static IP addresses.  These IP addresses would be in the same subnet as your other devices, but outside the DHCP range specified in your router.  (Most routers will have a DHCP range which is smaller then the subnet).   The key thing though is to not specify a default gateway.
On Windows 7 you will want to ensure IPV6 is disabled on the off chance that IPV6 autoconfiguration is happening.
The thing is that the threat you face is probably different to the one you perceive.  You state "I've heard that Windows XP will be attacked while idle; even if it doesn't actually browse the Internet.".   This is correct, but even if not explicitly configured  Your router is very, very likely acting as a de-facto firewall, preventing incoming connections on IPV4 by virtue of the fact that your network will be behind NAT.   If your IP addresses start with 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x or 172.16-31.x.x you are using NAT.
What you are saying about RDP is unclear.  If you are using RDP on your LAN, the above will work, but if you are trying to reach in to your XP/Windows 7 computer remotely, or reach out to other computers from these devices, that won't work.
Why not replace Windows XP / Windows 7 with a modern lightweight Linux distro instead?  Linux is very good at doing file sharing if so configured - indeed most NAS's (Including the Synology lineup) you purchase use a variant of Linux under the hood. https://www.techradar.com/best/best-nas-and-media-server-distros might be worth a read.

I edited this to indicate that I'm interested in local RDP only. I will try the non-specified gateway trick and report back.  The rabbit-hole reason I need these old boxes is too much to type.

Finally tried this on the Win7 box.  I disabled IPv6 and set the IPv4 to be static with no default gateway specified.  The subnet mask and DNS remained correct.  Although It did not have Internet access, it also did not have LAN access either.  So, I'm back to my original problem.
